# Merge two branches to create new branch

Tags: git, version-control

We have a few branches...

- `master` is our dev branch.
- `feature-newfeature` is a new feature.
- `feature-tempfeature` is a new feature that our product team have asked for until new feature is created. `feature-newfeature` was started a while ago and hasn't been merged into `master` yet (but there have been other changes to `master`).

We have now been instructed to put this temp feature in which needs all the changes from `master` - so its a releasable build - but also needs some of the stuff we've been working on in `newfeature` (as they say "you can reuse some of the stuff you've already done").

How would it be best to go about doing this? I have created `feature-tempfeature` from the `master` branch. `feature-newfeature` isn't finished, and I don't want to merge it into master.

I don't want to just use `feature-newfeature` either because we want to be able to keep working on that in parallel.

How would you sort out this issue in your dev environment?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

branches are just aliases for a specific commit. Therefore you can have multiple branches that actually point to the same commit. So, what you could do is to create a new branch `newBranch` that points to the same commit as master and then merge `feature-tempfeature` into `newBranch`. The effect would be the same as merging into master, except that master stays untouched.

Comment: Oh cool! That's pretty straightforward! Could I instead merge `master` into `newfeature` and then merge `newfeature` into `tempfeature` which will mean that my `newfeature` is up to date with the master as well?

Comment: Also presumably that will stop me having to merge master twice? Once now for `tempfeature` and again in the future with `newfeature`

Comment: 1. Yes, of course. Branching works in all directions.
2. Yes. You could also use `git-cherry-pick` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to apply changes of certain commits selectively.

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding your scenario is:

```
---master----
\___tempf____
\___newf_____
```

**Your problem:** You need `tempf` with changes of `master` as well as `newf` so

**Solution:**

1) Stash your unsaved changes in `tempf` with `$ git stash`

2) Merge master with tempf and merge newf with tempf to have the changes of the both master and newf

3) Stash pop your changes with `$ git stash pop`

And as @MaxLeske said, branches are just aliases, they serve just like pointer to a commit but are not the commits themselves.

Comment: `git stash` what a great command, didn't know you could do that. I have been committing or resetting files all this time. :) Thanks for your answer.